Как сделать пользовательскую функцию для всех открываемых файлов?
Создал пользовательскую функцию в excel. Хотел чтобы эта функция была доступна при открытии любого файла excel. Создал личную книгу макрос, создал там модуль, вставил туда код, после в строке разработчика наживаю на макрос, выбираю его, а он не работает. Но если создавать макрос отдельно для каждого файла, то все работаем. Но заморачиваться постоянно, при каждом открытии документа не хочется. Помогите советом.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вот первый совет: как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@aleksandrbarakin, как ты представляешь пример? Вроде всё нормально сформулировано.

@Qwertiy но почему-то ведь не работает то, что, как считает автор вопроса, должно работать. возможно, проблема в самом коде, возможно, в процедуре его добавления в (понятия не имею, что это) «книгу макрос».

Код отельно работает, а вот если запускать через личную книгу макрос - нет.

Код отельно работает, а вот если запускать через личную книгу макрос - нет - т.е., ещё больше должны сгуститься подозрения, что проблема возинкает именно из-за содержимого кода. ну, я понятия не имею, как там пользоваться этим excel-ем, ms/windows вообще и макросами в частности. но, предположим, в вашем коде используются какие-нибудь функции, которые интерпретатор выполняетт по-разному в зависимости от того, где именно сохранён этот ваш код. без mcve определить, правильное ли это подозрение - вряд ли возможно.

@aleksandrbarakin, не думаю, что проблема в коде. Вполне может быть, что код верный, но работает только в текущей книге потому что: 1. Из-за настроек безопасности он работает пока файл не закрыли - если сохранить, закрыть и открыть снова, то уже не заработает. (Это вообще поведение по умолчанию) 2. Настройки безопасности не позволяют загружать код для всех книг, но для конкретного файла срабатывает запрос. 3. Код для всех книг он помещает куда-то не в тот файл, который вообще не загружается при запуске экселя, а значит открываемым книгам ничего не светит.

@aleksandrbarakin, а вот что такое "книгу макрос" я тоже не очень понял, но по идее это должен быть какой-то общий шаблон, куда можно вносить общий код. Мне кажется, что что-то такое есть, но я не уверен. Кстати, вариант 4: код он внёс в шаблон нового документа, соответсвенно новые файлы будут создаваться с макросом внутри них, но для открываемых других макроса не будет.

@aleksandrbarakin, в общем, по сути ответом на этот вопрос должно быть: 1. в каких местах какие настройки надо поменять, чтобы глобальные макросы для всех книг были разрешены (и/или работали по запросу), особенно, если макросы не подписанные (наверняка же подписи у автора нет). 2. В какой файл надо поместить код.

@Qwertiy, вот примерно половину выдвинутых вами гипотез автор вопроса и смог бы подтвердить/отвергнуть, если бы последовал совету создать и приложить к вопросу mcve.

@WhiteList, ответь на эти вопросы: 1. Если ты сохраняешь файл с макросом, потом полностью закрываешь excel (не  только этот файл), и открываешь сохранённый файл, то во-первых, что происходит, во-вторых, работает ли макрос. 2. В какой файл ты загнал макрос, который должен работать во всех файлах, но не работает? 3. Если ты при наличии общего кода запускаешь эксель как программу (без открытия файлаЮ с созданием нового по умолчанию), код работает?

@aleksandrbarakin, но на возможность ответа на вопрос это вообще не влияет - либо отвечающий знает как сделать, чтобы заработало, или не знает.

Я вроде разобрался. Но появилась новая проблема как сделать чтобы пользовательская функция отображались через знак =.

@WhiteList, если разобрался, то напиши ответ с шагами, что надо сделать, чтобы оно работало. Про автокомплит лучше спросить отдельным вопросом.


Я нажал на fx (вставить функцию). 2. Потом в категории выбрал определенные пользователем (это имеется ввиду функции). 3. Выбрал функцию и уже нужно выбрать аргумент функции.


Но почему она не отображается через знак =.

Нужно сохранить книгу с функциями как Add-In, тогда точно будет работать, см. Making your custom functions available anywhere.
